# OOB CQWP messes up dropdowns background in IE9

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

1. Create a new publishing site
2. Drop a CQWP onto a page, you dont even need to configure it
3. Click SiteActions menu

**Problem**: The background for the menu becomes transparent!

I only have this issue in IE9, IE7 renders it fine. If I remove the CQWP and try any other web part, things are fine.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Does this site have a custom master page or custom css changes?

Comment: Nope, in fact, i just tried this on a newly created OOB Publishing Portal site. The default landing page has a CQWP and the SiteActions background is transparent. If I close that CQWP, the menu background fixes itself!

Comment: Changing to IE7 mode seems to fix it (default master page setting is IE=8). Not ideal, so it must be a CSS thing.    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />

Answer (score 3):

This is not a CSS issue. I don't know how to fix it properly, but I can add this information:
Issue occurs in IE 9 with hardware acceleration turned on for any SharePoint 2010 page with a content query web part added. Affects SharePoint menus (Site Actions) and some other forms of drop-down menu add ins.

The reason the IE7 mode etc. works, you're then viewing pages without hardware acceleration. IE 9 with this turned off also works fine but hardware acc. is supposedly one of the main advantages of IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to IE7 mode with a custom master page seems to fix it (default master page setting is IE=8). Not ideal, so it must be a CSS thing.